# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<T>'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-entities, hierarchical-data, silverlight-5.0

I am trying to create a query in my domain service (VS 2010 Silverlight Business Application) that returns the results from inspection readings that came out as a specific value, my database is set up as:

```
Locations
  a) Inspections
     b) InspectionItems
        c) InspectionReadings       
  a) Areas
     b) Inspections
        c) InspectionItems
           d) InspectionReadings
```

So, as you can see, there are inspection readings for locations under areas and locations. I have a POCO called name StatusList:

```
    public class StatusList
    {
        [Key]
        [Editable(false)]
        public Guid ID { get; set; }

        public string LocationName { get; set; }

        public DateTime LastInspectionDate { get; set; }

        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
```

which I am using to return the results of the query:

```
    public IQueryable<StatusList> GetLocationStatus()
    {
        var status = (from location in this.ObjectContext.Locations
                      where location.InspectionReadings.Status == value
                      orderby a.DateTaken                          
                      select new LocationStatusList()
                      {
                          ID = a.ID,
                          LocationName = d.Name,                              
                      }).ToList<StatusList>();
        return status;              
    }
```

unfortunately, it's returning the error in the title and I have no idea why as the list is clearly a list item and i have converted the results

```
.ToList<LocationStatusList>
```

Comment: Why would you return an `IQueryable` in `GetLocationStatus`? `IQueryable` is (informally speaking) used for  representing enumerable things in remote locations. You created a local list as your result. That is simply an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Is that LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Enities? It seems like the latter to me.

Comment: It's LINQ to Entitites - mistagged sorry!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The problem is precisely *because* you've called `ToList()`. You've declared that you're returning `IQueryable<LocationStatusList>`, and `List<T>` doesn't implement `IQueryable<T>`.

Options (pick one):

- Remove the `ToList` call
- Change the return type to `IEnumerable<LocationStatusList>`, `IList<LocationStatusList>` or possibly `List<LocationStatusList>`
- Call `AsQueryable()` after `ToList()`:

  ```
  ... as before ...
  .ToList().AsQueryable();
  ```

Note that you don't need the type argument in the `ToList` call - it's the same one that the compiler would infer anyway.

Comment: I had come to this conclusion immediately before I read this post! Thank you - your answer explains why I had it wrong it the first place. I am not sure why I had ToList().